# Fake url using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I just build up a WordPress site, and I want to hide the `wp-login.php` from the user. so I want to add a rewriteRule in the `.htaccess` file, something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterRemove 01286
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress


# the following line was added by me
RewriteRule ^my-login\.php$ /wp-login.php [L]
# end

</IfModule>
```

But unfortunately, It doesn't work. can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: Move this new rule before `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`

Comment: Thanks. now it works